# Crash not appearing in firebase issues after adding a new app to existing app

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, crashlytics

There is a an app on firebase and on Android studio.These apps was not connected and I connected both of them. But I could not change `package name`in firebase So I changed `applicationId`in Android studio.The android app was created in kotlin.I added this

```
 throw new RuntimeException("Test Crash"); // Force a crash
```

to `OnCreate`.After 5 min I could see in Firebase from **Crash-free statistics** part one issue was reported. But **Issues** part it says `No issues found`.If create new app in firebase it works fine. But I want to connect with already created firebase app.So how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Do you have data sharing enabled through Firebase Settings>Integrations>Google Analytics? Does the bundle ID in your google services file match the bundle ID in Firebase?

Comment: @OlegKodysh Yes. If create new app in firebase it works fine. But I want to connect with already created firebase app.

Comment: Could you provide your bundle ID either in this comment thread or in a private message to me? I would like to check the Firebase backend for the status of your app.